# Build action for resource dictionary in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, resourcedictionary

What should the build action for a resource dictionary? In WPF it's **Resource** build action for `ResourceDictionary` file, but in UWP there no such a build action, and googling didn't help so far.

I tried several options like **Embedded Resource** and so on but all of them just cause different exceptions.

The project works without using the `ResourceDictionary` file and there is just one simple style in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ResourceDictionary` the setup should look as in this screenshot:

[image: Resource dictionary properties]

So the *Build Action* is **Page** and the *Custom Tool* should be **XamlIntelliSenseFileGenerator**.

If you are still getting an exception, ensure that the XAML code is valid or alternatively right-click a folder in your project, select **Add** > **Add new item...**, select **XAML** category on the left and then **Resource Dictionary** template and let Visual Studio create the correct file for you.